# Dynamically change div content in a form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created one login page with some error message.But I am able to display only single error message.My Requirement is very simple.
I have 2 fields `email` and `password` when I click `go` button if there is no email it should display `enter email`.If I have entered invalid email it should display `invalid email`.
Similary for password two validation `enter password`and `enter valid password`. 
 
 For this I need to add error messages dynamically.Can anybody help me ?please.

https://jsfiddle.net/jnzk9gv4/

Comment: I'm not shure, but you can add some extra funcions inside the .show() to output the error. Like .show( function() { etc. });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way here is to simply change the message when you detect a problem.

here you have: https://jsfiddle.net/jnzk9gv4/7/

```
var error = "";
if (!emailReg.test(userEmail)) {
    error = "Invalid email";
} else if (userEmail=="") {
    error = "Enter email";
} else if (!passReg.test(userPassword)) {
    error = "Invalid password";
} else if (userPassword=="") {
    error = "Enter password";
}
if (error != "") {
    $("#errorMessage").text(error);
    $(".invalidData").show();
} else {
    $(".invalidData").hide();
}
```

Comment: please check it.If I Don't enter password its showing invalid password.But it should display `enter password` right?

Comment: @user7397787 That's beucase `passReg.test` fires when password is empty. Just switch the if statements so empty password is checked first. The same for empty email.

Comment: Ya got it.Thanks Can you please tell me that Is this ajax  correct for my code to pass email and password..please let me know ` e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('login').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });`

Comment: Nope. You are not selecting login by id. It should be done this way: `$('#login').serialize()`. Note the hashtag. Also, if this answer fits your needs, accept it, please.